# is there something wrong with my recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to create neat algorithm from scratch, but I meet this problem where the value just wrong when I tried my input and giving the value all 0.5

I have searching all through my code but i still don't know what's wrong with my code

```
double Individu::calculateNodeValue(Node *&node) {

    int size = node->getConn_in().size();
    double value = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Connection *tempConn = node->getConn_in()[i];
        if (tempConn->getNodeFrom()->getValue() == 0 && !tempConn->getNodeFrom()->isInput()) {
            value += (calculateNodeValue(tempConn->getNodeFrom()) * tempConn->getWeight());
        }
        else {
            value += (tempConn->getNodeFrom()->getValue() * tempConn->getWeight());
        }
    }
    node->setValue(value);
    return node->activatedValue();
}
```

the output just seem really wrong it seems like the value it's given is just out of nowhere and I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Could you please explain what the neat algorithm is supposed to do so we can verify it? And what is the input? A [mcve] would be the best

Comment: I highly recommend a [mcve], including input, output, and desired output.I also recommend stepping through in a debugger and finding the line that differs from what you expect. You'll probably figure out the problem at that point.

Comment: Just to check the obvious, does node->setValue(value) change the same value that is returned by node->activatedValue() ?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its basically neural network with genetic algorithm which node and connection mutated, so i couldnt just iterate layer per layer , instead node to node which every node have vector of connection pointer in and out,

Comment: @o_weisman setvalue just set the value and  activateValue, activating the value(with sigmoid) and then return that activatedValue

Comment: @chris i'll check it out, thankyou

Comment: Even if I got lucky with finding this as explanation ( https://towardsdatascience.com/neat-an-awesome-approach-to-neuroevolution-3eca5cc7930f ) you should still add a summary of the desired algorithm. It might help to write "NEAT" algorithm, instead of neat algorithm. The latter read as a very unspecific adjective to me.... (My mistake of course, but maybe more get confused by our lack of knowledge.)